# writing and estimating Likelihood functions with EM algorithm in R

Tags: r

What package in [r](/questions/tagged/r) enables the writing of a log likelihood function given some data and then estimating it using the EM algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Expectation_Maximization_(EM) and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811541/numeric-example-of-the-expectation-maximization-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like [flexmix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/) or [mixtools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/index.html). They work out of the box for a number of standard models but can be used with user supplied likelihoods as well. The latter (user defined models) is less straightforward and depending on your application it may be easier/faster/better to write customized code.